# When things sink?

Tags: density

Why a heavy object over a less dense medium doesn't fall always to the bottom? Think: stone on balls of polystyrene. Why do the balls stick together and don't let the stone sink to the bottom? - (provided you are not shaking the box)

Comment: you should see Thrust.

Answer (score 2):

The notion of buoyancy really only applies to fluids or very plastic/glassy solids, so might not be something to look at with the polystyrene beads. However, if we want to model it like a liquid, there are also the factors of "surface tension" and "viscosity" to consider: polystyrene beads are often electrostatically bound to each other, creating an effective surface tension that the stone must overcome to sink. Something similar happens when a rock sits on sand: it doesn't sink in because too much energy is required to physically separate the sand particles. In other cases, the liquid may be so viscous that the sinking is imperceptibly slow.